# 2 forms with one submit button $_POST method

Tags: javascript, php, forms, submit

i want to combine 2 forms into one submit button on separate parts of the website. its pretty much a check box deletion mysql row script. here is a picture.

[image]

What I am trying to do is have DELETE SELECTED, delete the selected checkedboxes rows that are on the left side.

I am unable to get that to work.

My form names are **delete1** for the button and **delete2** for the whole table as a form.

I tried to combine both forms into one by using javascript.

```
function functionCaller()
{
document.getElementById('delete1').submit();
document.getElementById('delete2').submit();
}
```

It doesnt seem to work.

Does anyone have any ideas, I pretty much want to use a submit button on another part of the page that corresponds to being the submit button for the check boxes, while not being part of the same form. I hope it makes sense.

UPDATE. ADDED CODE.

The form for the **DELETE SELECTED** button seperated from the table

```
<form action="" method="post" name="delete">
<div style=" float: right;">
<input type="submit" value="Delete Selected" id="delete" onclick="functionCaller()" name="delete">
</div>
</form>
```

Here is the form that contains the table

```
<form action="" method="post" name="delete">
   <div class="table">
      <div class="table-head">
         <div data-label="select" class="column"><input type="checkbox" id="selectall"></div>
         <div data-label="id" class="column">ID</div>
         <div data-label="avatar" class="column">Avatar</div>
         <div data-label="username" class="column">Username</div>
         <div data-label="email" class="column">Email</div>
         <div data-label="active" class="column">Active</div>
         <div data-label="level" class="column">Level</div>
         <div data-label="modify" class="column">Modify</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div data-label="select" class="column"><input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox[]" value="94" onclick="resetSelectAll();"></div>
         <div data-label="id" class="column">94</div>
         <div data-label="avatar" class="column"><img alt="" src="uploads/540d248343caa.JPG"></div>
         <div data-label="username" class="column">admin</div>
         <div data-label="email" class="column">brian.cherdak@gmail.com</div>
         <div data-label="active" class="column">Yes</div>
         <div data-label="level" class="column">Admin</div>
         <div data-label="modify" class="column"><a href="admin_update.php?id=94"><img alt="" src="images/tool.png"></a>  <a onclick="delete_user(94);" href="#"><img alt="" src="images/delete.png"></a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div data-label="select" class="column"><input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox[]" value="287" onclick="resetSelectAll();"></div>
         <div data-label="id" class="column">287</div>
         <div data-label="avatar" class="column"><img alt="" src="uploads/54052a0accd62.gif"></div>
         <div data-label="username" class="column">Quyn</div>
         <div data-label="email" class="column">brian.cherdak@gmail.com</div>
         <div data-label="active" class="column">Yes</div>
         <div data-label="level" class="column">Regular</div>
         <div data-label="modify" class="column"><a href="admin_update.php?id=287"><img alt="" src="images/tool.png"></a>  <a onclick="delete_user(287);" href="#"><img alt="" src="images/delete.png"></a></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

They are both on seperate sides of the page, but I want the delete button to pretty much be the delete button for the table form.

This is what my delete php code looks like

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['checkbox']);$i++){
$del_id = $_POST['checkbox'][$i];
$sql_del = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id='$del_id'";
$result_del = mysql_query($sql_del);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: you haven't nested the two forms have you ?

Comment: OliverBS, no I havent, I dont think HTML allows that.

Comment: Please show the HTML. This image doesn't give enough information. Also does submitting a form use ajax or does it reload the whole page?

Comment: @Popnoodles I have added code to my post.

Comment: @BrianCherdak html can do whatever you want mate

Comment: So I can nest the form inside of another form? @OliverBS

Comment: All you really had to do was wrap the form around both the button and the table-like structure instead of having two forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer after comment:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="delete1" id='form1' method="POST" onsubmit="merge(); return true;">
<div style=" float: right;">
<input type="submit">
</div>
</form>

<form action="" method="post" name="delete2" id='form2'>
    // your checkboxes...
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function merge() {
        $result = $("#form1");
        $("#form2 input, #form2 select").each(function() {
            if($(this).is(':checked')){
                $result.append("<input type='hidden' name='"+$(this).attr('name')+"' value='"+$(this).val()+"' />");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you really sure? If you do a submit the browser starts a new request and will leave the current page either.

Comment: And if the two forms point to different pages or have the same input fields..? I think ajax may be required here. If it uses ajax, the original answer was correct.

Comment: Ronak Patel, how can this be modified to work on my example? I technically only have 1 form and 1 submit button. the other one with the check boxes doesnt have a submit button.

Comment: @BrianCherdak there is too much guessing taking place. Show some code.

Comment: @BrianCherdak: Do you need to submit those check box value in same URL? If is that so then you can append your checkbox tags in your main form and submit that form. Consider `form1` as your checkboxes.

Comment: Popnoodles Okay, I will add it as a Answer Your Question comment.

Comment: @RonakPatel, I am slightly confused, I have added my code to the website.

Comment: @BrianCherdak: check my update... This way you can merge your two forms, and submit it by one click.

Comment: @RonakPatel, it seems to work now, but it is deleting rows that are not selected by the checkbox, pretty much every row that shows up on the page. How do I make it only delete the rows that are selected.

Comment: @BrianCherdak: form that you need to check this condition in `php`. if checkbox is selected then delete certain row.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61123/discussion-between-brian-cherdak-and-ronak-patel).

Comment: I already have that code. 

`if(isset($_POST['checkbox']))
{
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['checkbox']);$i++){
$del_id = $_POST['checkbox'][$i];
$sql_del = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id='$del_id'";
$result_del = mysql_query($sql_del);
}
}`

Comment: I'm glad this works but if you now look at the HTML that was given you can see that only one form needs posting anyway. OP for whatever reason had the button in one form and the fields in the other.

Answer (score 1):

That submit function is no good. Only the first submission is happening.
I would set a hidden input value in the delete form. I haven't tested this, but I think everyone will get the idea.

Here's some jQuery:

```
functionCaller = function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // Just to be sure the submit doesn't go without us
    var a = []
    $(':checkbox').each(function(){
        if($(this).prop('checked') === true) a.push($(this).val());
    });
    $('#hidden_input').val(a.toString()); // Explode by , (comma) in php
    document.getElementById('delete1').submit(); // Do form submit now
}
```

Some PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
$a = explode(','$_POST['hidden_input']);
    for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++){
        $del_id = $a[$i];
        $sql_del = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id='$del_id'";
        $result_del = mysql_query($sql_del);
    }
}
```

HTML!:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="delete">
<div style=" float: right;">
<input type="submit" value="Delete Selected" id="delete" onclick="functionCaller()" name="delete">
<input type="hidden" value="" id="hidden_input" name="hidden_input">
</div>
</form>
```